# Combining 2 queries into 1 both queries have different tables and summation

Tags: sql, oracle

How Do I combine these 2 queries into one?

```
 select 
    count(case when sd_code in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log
                                       where QA_date is null) then 1 end) as Changes,
    count(case when sd_code in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log
                                       where QA_date is not null) then 1 end) as Complete
    from sdrp15_cosd
```

gives me the result

```
   CHANGES   COMPLETE
---------- ----------
       629        210
```

and

```
select a.phase,a.st_code||' - '||b.state_name,
case when a.submission_received_dt is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as Changes
from pcspro.sdrp15_return a,
pcspro.sdrp15_states_ready b 
where a.phase = b.phase and a.st_code = b.state;
```

gives me the result

```
PHASE A.ST_CODE||'-'||B.STATE_NAME        CHANGES
----- ----------------------------------- -------
A     01 - Alabama (AL)                   Y      
A     01 - Alabama (AL)                   Y      
A     16 - Idaho (ID)                     Y      
A     30 - Montana (MT)                   Y      
A     56 - Wyoming (WY)                   Y
```

and is it possible to create a row that''ll appear at the end, that totals changes and complete?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are looking for in your second question?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, something like this should work:

```
SELECT sum(CASE 
            WHEN sdc.sd_code IN (
                    SELECT ss.sd_code
                    FROM sdrp15_submission_log ss
                    WHERE ss.QA_date IS NULL
                    )
                THEN 1
           ELSE 0
            END) AS Changes
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN sdc.sd_code IN (
                    SELECT sdl.sd_code
                    FROM sdrp15_submission_log sdl
                    WHERE sdl.QA_date IS NOT NULL
                    )
                THEN 1
          ELSE 0
            END) AS Complete
FROM sdrp15_cosd sdc
```